# CodeIgniter white screen on local dev environment

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, heroku, vagrant

I'm working on local creating developer environments for a CodeIgniter application.  The production application runs on Heroku so I'm not familiar with the production server configuration.

I'm creating the developer environments with Vagrant, Ansible, Ubuntu 14.04, Apache 2.4, and PHP 5.  The Apache2 modules I'm using are mod_proxy, mod_proxy_fcgi, php5, and rewrite.

I get a white screen when I load the application in the browser.

How can I begin to diagnose the white screen?

Comment: WRT codeigniter, what have you tried??

Comment: @Niranjan WRT CodeIgniter, I haven't tried anything.  I'm unfamiliar with CodeIgniter, thanks!

Comment: in url , u ve index.php??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261969/blank-screen-with-codeigniter

Comment: a white page is usually a symptom of a 500 ISE. Use curl -v and you'll likely confirm that. If that's the case, it's something to do with code igniter or php, or configuration. Without more information it's impossible to help diagnose. You'll want to look at how to diagnose PHP 500 errors.