# CodeIgniter screen showing blank

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter code is working great on my local. I uploaded pages to live server I can see the login page, once I enter username and password I see a blank page. I made necessary base_url changes:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://myurl.com/incidents/';
$config['index_page'] = 'backend.php';
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `$config['index_page'] = 'backend.php';` should be `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to configure routes look in to http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: what setup does your life server have ? is it nginx + php-fpm or apache with php fcgi etc .. what is your local stack ? there migth be some other differences why things are not working

Comment: #DarkMukke I have godaddy linux, PHP environment. On my local I am running Xammp

Answer (score 0):

PHP version was causing the problem. On my local I have 5.6.8 and on Godaddy and bluehost were using 5.4.x. For testing purposes I've uploaded my files to two different hosting environments and got the same error. As a result I just wanted to upgrade the bluehost php version and the application works fine now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

There may be errors on your page. You can display them by setting `ENVIRONMENT` to `development` in your `index.php`

Also, make sure your target page link (when you click login) is properly routed.

**Edit:**

Try adding the following lines to the top of your `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Comment: Did you make sure your `.htaccess` file got uploaded properly?

Comment: And, have you tried this? [http://stackoverflow.com/a/19197074/4274918](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19197074/4274918)

Comment: .htaccess as follows. I am not sure if this is what you mean.          'RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|backend\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]'

Comment: It's CodeIgniter... simply set `ENVIRONMENT` to `development` and all errors will be shown.

Comment: switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
 case 'development':
  error_reporting(-1);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 break;

 case 'testing':
 case 'production':
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
  if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
  {
   error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
  }
  else
  {
   error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
  }
 break;

 default:
  header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
  echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
  exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
NO ERROR msg

Comment: It could be a database issue. Look at this thread. And try the checklist. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1262394/4274918](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1262394/4274918)

Comment: Try this first. Then the checklist from the link above. Set `$db['default']['db_debug']` to `TRUE`

Comment: try to execute this code on the suspecting file(s): error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); see if it helps.